# Can't get my function to do anything

Tags: python, python-3.x

Working on a program that "encrypts" and "decrypts" an input string, no matter how I arrange my returns or function calls. I feel like something is stupidly out of place, but I'm at my wits end to have this actually do what it needs to.  It'll go through the first input questions, then never executes the function I ask it to.

```
def DecryptMe(strEncryptedInput):
    for key in range(1,101):
        strDecrypt = strEncryptedInput
        strDecryptedOutput = ''
        for c in strDecrypt:
            if (ord(c) - key < 32):
                DecryptedInteger =((ord(c) - key) + 127 - 32)
                strDecryptedOutput = strDecryptedOutput + chr(DecryptedInteger)
            else:
                DecryptedInteger = (ord(c) - key)
                strDecryptedOutput = strDecryptedOutput + chr(DecryptedInteger)

        print(key,"= ",strDecryptedOutput)

def EncryptMe(strDecryptedInput,key):
    strEncrypt = strDecryptedInput
    strEncryptedOutput = ''
    for c in strEncrypt:
        if (ord(c) - key < 32):
            EncryptedInteger = ((ord(c) + key) - 127 + 32)
            strEncryptedOutput = strEncryptedOutput + chr(EncryptedInteger)
        else:
            EncryptedInteger = (ord(c) + key)
            strEncryptedOutput = strEncryptedOutput + chr(EncryptedInteger)
    return strEncryptedOutput


strChoice = input("Please either chose to (E)ncrypt or (D)ecrypt a message.")
if strChoice == "e" or strChoice == "E":
    strDecrypedInput = ""
    strInput = input("Please type the string you wish to encrypt and press the Enter key.")
    intKeyInput = int(input("Please enter a key from 1 to 100 to encrypt the message with."))
    EncryptMe(strDecryptedInput = strInput,key = intKeyInput)
    print(strDecryptedInput,"= ",strEncryptedOutput, " Key = ",key)


elif strChoice == "d" or strChoice =="D":
        print("")
else:
    print("")

#key = 88
#DecryptMe(":mmZ\dxZmx]Zpgy")
#EncryptMe(strDecryptedInput,key)
Mode()
```

Comment: since python is white space significant, you should please take care to make sure the code you posted is indented the same as what you have locally. In the posting above, your function definitions have nothing indented below them; this would cause them to have an empty body if this is what you have locally.

Comment: First time I've posted code, I didn't realize the Ctrl+K key would indent everything and did it manually. Whoops!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you might try changing these two lines:

```
EncryptMe(strDecryptedInput = strInput,key = intKeyInput)
print(strDecryptedInput,"= ",strEncryptedOutput, " Key = ",key)
```

to this

```
strEncryptedOutput = EncryptMe(strDecryptedInput = strInput,key = intKeyInput)
print(strInput,"= ",strEncryptedOutput, " Key = ", str(intKeyInput))
```

I ran your code with these modifications (on Python 3.5.1) and the encryptor runs beautifully :)